# Powershell: Tail a log and process each line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, tail

I need to create a system to monitor a log in real time and send an alert if an IP is foreign.

I would prefer to use powershell (v2, due to server retraint) to accomplish this as I've got a system that processes the previous day's log already and I'd be able to reuse a lot of that functionality.

I can successfully tail the file (using tail.exe) and select the important lines, but I can't seem to capture each line and process it.

The basic gist of what I have is:

```
tail.exe -f \\server\file.log | where-object {$_ -match "criteria"}
```

When I try to pipeline the results into a foreach, I get nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tail command is going to block the pipeline as long as it's running.  One option is to run the tail in a background job, and process the results in your main script in an endless loop:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { tail.exe -f \\server\file.log }

 While ($true){
 Recieve-Job $Job | 
 Where-Object { $_ -match "criteria" }
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```

Comment: This is working.  I'm able to get the data from `$job`.  The problem is that the job just keeps appending data.  

I think I need to leave GC/tail behind and move to a streamReader of some sort.  Then I can process each line easily.

Comment: ...but for anyone reading this behind me, using powershell v3 and `-tail 1` you can easily process it one event-line at a time.

Comment: Final solution was to use a stream.  `$sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader(new-object System.IO.FileStream("$filename", "open", "Read","ReadWrite"))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST use "tail.exe", use "&" to make the line execute all together like it would in the command prompt. Then split the output by "`n" (new line). After that, you can find lines that match what you're looking for and either write them to the console or write them to another log file.

```
$log = "\\server\file.log"
$tail = & tail.exe -f $log | ?{$_ -split "`n"}
Foreach($line in $tail)
{
    if($line -match "this")
    {
        Write-Host $line
        Out-File -InputObject $line -FilePath \\server\important-logs.log
    }
}
```

Comment: For PowerShell version 2, try:

`get-content \\server\file.log -Wait | ?{$_ -match "criteria"}`

For PowerShell version 4, try:

`Get-Content \\server\file.log -Tail 10 | ?{$_ -match "criteria"}`
`# -Tail 10 can be any number of lines.`

I hope that helps.

T.CK

Answer (score -1):

Just use the Get-Content PowerShell Cmndlet and it will return a System.Array object.

```
$Content = Get-Content "Path to log.log" | ? { $_ -match "something" }
```

Comment: `tail -f` "follows" a file as additional data is being appended to it. `Get-Content` can do that with the parameter `-Wait`, but that wasn't introduced before PowerShell v3, while the OP is restricted to v2.

Comment: I've rarely needed instantaneous alerting of something in a log, so I missed that.  Good catch Ansgar.

Comment: Actually, `get-content -wait` was in v2, but `-Tail n`  wasn't.  So, it's true that `gc -wait` is effectively the same as `tail.exe -f`.  Ideally, I would do `gc -wait -tail 1`, which on v3 would give me one line at a time until the file is closed.  

However, I believe the `-wait` is blocking the pipeline as @mjolinor mentioned.

Comment: @user3195248 Ah, you're right. I merely checked `Get-Help Get-Content` (which doesn't list the option) without trying to actually run the command.